# Reading previous lines from a specific string in a file

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to read a specific line from a textfile using VBScript. First of all, I am searching for a specific string in a textfile then trying to read 4<sup>th</sup> line present above that specific string.

Example: Suppose, I am looking for a string 'CAT' in a textfile. I found this string at line no 1763. Now, I am trying to write the content present at line no. 1759. I know that I am not looping in a right way to get the string once I get the row no. Please suggest.

```
Dim Count
Dim strline

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\PSi\Both.txt", ForReading)

Const ForReading = 1
Count = 0

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    Count=Count+1
    If instr(strLine, "CAT") <> 0 Then
        Count = Count-4
        Exit Do
    End If 
Loop
'This section of code not working..
'Error : Input past end of file 
For i=1 To Count-4
    objFile.ReadLine
Next
strline = objFile.ReadLine
MsgBox strline

objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah because you already iterated through the objFile, you reached the end, and it's trying to go back to the end. Instead of trying to run through the contents of the file twice, save the file into an array and go through it as many times as you want.

```
Dim a, text: a = "C:\testenv\test.log"
text = split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(a, 1).ReadAll, vbcrlf)

'Round 1
for i=0 to ubound(text)
    'operate on each line here text(i)
next

'Round 2
for i=0 to ubound(text)
    'operate on each line here text(i)
next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read files backwards (unless you read the entire file into an array, which could exhaust memory if you have a large file), but you can use a [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_buffer) for keeping a history of the previous n lines you read from the file:

```
filename = "C:\Users\PSi\Both.txt"
bufsize  = 5 'number of lines to keep in the ring buffer

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'create and initialize ring buffer
ReDim buf(bufsize-1)
For n = 0 To UBound(buf)
  buf(n) = Null
Next

i = 0
matchFound = False

'read lines into ring buffer
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream Or matchFound
  buf(i) = f.ReadLine
  If InStr(buf(i), "CAT") > 0 Then matchFound = True
  i = (i+1) Mod bufsize
Loop
f.Close
```

If the buffer is completely filled, the array element `buf(i)` now contains the line you're looking for (4th line before the last line read from the file). Otherwise you can "fast-forward" to the first non-null element like this if less than 5 lines have been read from the file:

```
j = 0
Do While IsNull(buf(i)) And j < bufsize
  i = (i+1) Mod bufsize
  j = j + 1
Loop
```